# Mapping a string to an arbitrary data type?

Tags: solidity, mapping

It seems that Solidity can only handle mappings to elementary data types or structs. Is there some mapping that can handle arbitrary (dynamic) types for the values? Something like:

`mapping(string => any) foo;`

I have no clue how this would work.

Answer (score 3):

You can map to a `struct` which could be designed to suit your purpose, e.g,

```
struct MyType {
    uint someInt;
    bytes[] someBytes;
    ...
}

mapping (string => MyType) foo;
```

But if you mean `any` to simply be untyped, then no you can't do that.  You could perhaps use a `bytes[]` array and run the element through some manual type conversion functions which sounds much more complicated than simply designing your contract around strict types.